# Error in Groovy installation

Tags: unix, groovy

I have install Groovy 2.1.1 in my unix box. While executing **groovysh** getting the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: error:
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:346)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
Could not find the main class: error:.  Program will exit.
```

What could be the possible root cause for this error...???

Comment: what about trying `groovy -v` and `groovy -e ' println "echo" '`?

Comment: What steps did you take to _"install Groovy 2.1.1 in my unix box"_?

Comment: @Will P: same error is coming for this commands also...

Comment: @tim_yates: first, Download a binary distribution of Groovy and unpack it into some file on your local file system
set your GROOVY_HOME environment variable to the directory you unpacked the distribution
add GROOVY_HOME/bin to your PATH environment variable
set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your JDK. On OS X this is /Library/Java/Home, on other unixes its often /usr/java etc

Comment: Does `java -version` works?

Comment: @WillP: Yes java -version is working fine. Below is the output. But i am not able to see Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM. Is this the reason for this issue..?? If yes, how to get/enable the hotspot server..??

Comment: c141zfk:~ # java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460sr10fp1-20120321_01(SR10 FP1))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux amd64-64 jvmxa6460sr10fp1-20120202_101568 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20120202_101568
JIT  - r9_20111107_21307ifx1
GC   - 20120202_AA)
JCL  - 20120320_01

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, you try to use the class `error:` (and yes, Groovy thinks that the colon is part of the class name), either in the script you execute (i.e. there must be `new error:` somewhere) or you wrote something like `groovysh error:` or you import `error:` (maybe indirectly)

Comment: @Aron: still i didn't execute any scripts as of now. I just install groovy and configured it, and want to check that my installation is ok or not. in the command line simply i execute groovysh or groovyconsole, but for the both case the same error is coming.

Comment: Is there is any way to find out where this error: class is importing indirectly.....??  @Aron

Comment: Try `bash -x groovysh`; does that print something useful? The error looks as if something was wrong with the classpath or the command line passed to `groovy`

Comment: Thank you for the followup. I ran that command and got very big output. Below is the O/p.

Comment: + exec /usr/bin/java -classpath /usr/bin/build-classpath: error: JVM_LIBDIR /usr/lib64/jvm-exports//usr/bin/java:jre does not exist or is not a directory: -Dscript.name=groovysh -Dprogram.name=groovysh -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/etc/groovy-starter.conf -Dgroovy.home=/usr/bin -Dtools.jar=/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: JVM_LIBDIR /usr/lib64/jvm-exports//usr/bin/java:jre does not exist or is not a directory org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --conf /etc/groovy-starter.conf --main org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: error:

Comment: I think the possible root cause for this error is with the classpath. As i am very much inexperienced with unix desperately need your help....

Comment: You can redirect the output to a file with `bash -x groovysh >& error.log` Search for `JVM_LIBDIR` in the file `error.log` to see where it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using IBM J9, according to the [Grails FAQ](http://grails.org/FAQ#Q%3a%20Deploying%20under%20IBM%27s%20J9%20JVM%20%20%28applies%20to%20WebSphere%20installs%20too%29), the J9 need an argument to work well with Groovy, otherwise you may get a `NoClassDefFound` error:

Add `-Xverify:none` to JVM arguments

Answer (score 0):

Download Groovy Binary From http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download

Download zip: Binary Release

Extract Local Disk say D;\GROOVY\ groovy-2.3.9

It contains the Folder Structure
D:.
├───bin
├───conf
├───embeddable
├───indy
├───lib
└───META-INF

Go to Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts  Change My Environment Variables

Set/new GROOVY_HOME = D:\GROOVY\groovy-2.3.9 (don’t put : semicolon)

Set PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin;

Add groovy-all.jar to CLASSPATH

D:\ GROOVY\ \groovy-2.3.9\embeddable\groovy-all-2.3.9.jar;.

Close and Open Command and Say –groovy

For console -groovyConsole